# How to a create a pet paw logo using canvas in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a paw pet canvas as the below logo dynamically using flutter:

[image: Pet Paw logo]

as I tried to create a using `Paint()` Canvas as the below code:

```
class PetLogo extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // TODO: implement paint
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 3;

    Paint paint1 = Paint();
    paint1
      ..color = Colors.transparent
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 0;

    var paint2 = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 3;
    //a circle
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(0, 9), 18, paint2);

    var paint3 = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 3;
    //a circle
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(50, 0), 22, paint3);

    var paint4 = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 3;
    //a circle
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(100, 10), 18, paint4);

    double width = size.width;
    double height = size.height;

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0.5 * width, height * 0.45);
    path.cubicTo(0.2 * width, height * 0.1, -0.50 * width, height * 0.6,
        0.5 * width, height);
    path.moveTo(0.5 * width, height * 0.45);
    path.cubicTo(0.8 * width, height * 0.1, 1.50 * width, height * 0.6,
        0.5 * width, height);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint1);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

as the final output looks like the below figure:

[image: Fluuter code]

So there's any one could help me to complete this paint?

Comment: i dont see any bazier, you could use bazier for curves!

Comment: @Yadu thanks for your support could you give me some hint for this to complete the logo :D